# How to convert a Linux binary from AMD64 to AARCH64 architecture?

Tags: apt, updates, 64-bit, cross-compilation

I'm trying to convert a Linux binary from AMD64 to AARCH64 architecture, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I've searched online and found that typically, the source code is required for such conversions. However, when I looked into the provided source code, I couldn't find support for AARCH64 architecture.

The file I'm attempting to convert is: [Linux AMD64 Binary](https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dropbox.com%2Fs%2Fhtua92qiszh1g8e%2Flinux-amd64-librw_gl3_glfw-oal.7z%3Fdl%3D0)

And here's the source code I've been referring to: [Source Code](https://archive.org/download/re3_20210807/re3.rar/lcs%2Fre3-lcs.zip)

Could anyone guide me on how to perform this conversion or suggest alternative approaches? Any help would be great appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: converting is not going to work. you need to recode the source. qemu-user  is likely easier: https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/user/main.html

Answer (score 3):

I believe a very similar question has already been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756512/convert-binary-to-arm.

In short, you must obtain the source code to compile a binary in the target architecture of your like. According to the source code that you attached, it seems to belong to a reverse-engineered game named reLCS, which was taken down because of a DMCA complaint.

Reading this source code's `README.md` file, you can find a link pointing to a guide to compile the binary in Linux. Although the repository is now unavailable, you can still access it through the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20210904123827/https://github.com/GTAmodding/re3/wiki/Building-on-Linux. The page mentions that it can be compiled to `arm64`, so you could probably try following the specified steps and compile your required binary.